# How can I see subscribe and unsubscribe list in sitecore database

Tags: xdb, exm, list-manager

Where is the following `EXM information` stored in `Sitecore` database (version 9.2).

1. Subscribe list
2. Unsubscribe list

I have checked in the `Sitecore92_EXM.Master`database. But I was unable to find it. Please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of subscribed users is not stored on EXM.Master database .

The users/contacts subscribtion is stored in xdb database, in the shards databases.

To be more specific, this information is stored in ContactFacets table on ListSubscribtion facet

[image]

This is not very well documented but you can find some information here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/use-core-collection-model-facets.html#listsubscriptions-listsubscriptions

Comment: Thank you Vlad lobagiu.

Comment: if it helps you please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I need another one info. How do get the subscribe and unsubscribe list in code(using query or something). could you suggest.thanks

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10677/getting-list-of-contacts-assigned-to-contact-segmened-list-in-sitecore-9-0-1-p here is the answer for your 2nd question

Comment: Hi Vlad lobagiu, Do we get contact list based on the user?. EX. one user associated with multiple contact list. Is there any way to find users details in sitecore database. Thanks..