# How to get all Segmented lists for a contact

Tags: segmented-list, contact

Anyone have a smart way to get all the Segmented lists for a given contact?
I have 40 Segmented lists and I need to display a list of all to whom a contact is assigned at a given moment in the user panel in a relatively short time.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way of getting segmented list for a given contact. Is the other way round in Sitecore. Segmented list has a set of conditions and you can get contacts which fulfil them. So the only option would be in fact going through all segmented lists, getting contacts and checking if your contact is there. Segmented lists are quite optimized though so it should be quite fast. See https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10677/getting-list-of-contacts-assigned-to-contact-segmened-list-in-sitecore-9-0-1-p . Unless there is a way which I don't know about :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I expected. I wonder if the opposite can be done. Instead of lists, use items that have field rules and see which ones the user meets. I used to do something like this on the current user. The question is, is it possible to do something like this for the indicated contact downloaded by xconnect?

Comment: Share the code you used for current user. Maybe one will be able to help you to adapt it for your needs